# Addition reaction of alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image: The correct option is c]

Correct option is option c but option d also forms  same compound after 1,2hydride shift.So why only option a and b is possible why not d also??

Comment: Bro it seems to me that your doubt is correct ..... But actually the shift that should explain your doubt  is a 1,2 hydride shift and not a methyl shift . The only explanation to explain the answer of the module is that we don't consider the hydride and methide shifts but that won't be justified so I suggest you to consult your teacher

Comment: @AdityaGarg I just want to know that is there any condition that hydride shift will take place only from primary to secondary carbocation or it also do the same for shift of secondary to tertiary carbocation

Comment: No there isn't such a thing

Comment: No not necessarily

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> My answer explains why option D does not produce better yield of *1-chloro-1-methylcyclohexane*

[image: img 1]

As you can see *1-methylcyclohex-2-ene* reacts with $\ce{HCl}$ to give two *carbocation intermediates* one has more hyperconjugation structures and other having less.

> Increasing number of hyperconjugating structures meaning more stable carbocation and number of hyperconjucating structure depends on number of alpha hydrogen present in the carbocation.

Therefore, *1-chlorocyclohex-2-ene* yield **major** product *1-chloro-3-methylcyclohexane* and **minor** product is *1-chloro-1-methylcyclohexane*

> Hence option D is not correct, While the other two reactant yields major product *1-chloro-1-methylcyclohexane* see image below

[image: img 2]

> from above discussion we can say that option A and B will both produce good yield of *1-chloro-1-methylcyclohexane* so andwer is option C